# How do I delete a word from auto-correct?

Tags: auto-correct, vivo

So I'm trying to remove this impropriate word. Not gonna show you the word because it's impropriate. I tried many tricks, I tried long pressing and it didn't do anything and I tried to clear the google keyboard's data but I have a different phone so it doesn't work. The device I'm using is
a Vivo phone, the model number's 1811. Do anyone know how to remove words from the auto-correct? This is all the information I got.

Update,
It turns out I don't have GBoard so I downloaded it. I've been using my default keyboard the whole time. Sorry about my mistake.

Comment: Auto-correct is a feature of the used keyboard app. Which keyboard app do you use?

Comment: @Robert The question says "Clear Google Keyboard's data" so it should be gboard

Comment: @SrinivasV In the question you can read that "Clear Google Keyboard's data" is what did not work, therefore Google's keyboard app GBoard is installed, but it seems not to be the active keyboard.